# Zip / Unzip a Sencha Touch (or HTML/Js) application to reduce network cost

Tags: zip, sencha-touch, unzip

I'm planning to develop a Sencha Touch application, which is likely to be around 1Mo of code. Now, this is quite a bit to download from a mobile phone and I would like to know if there is a way to zip/unzip the whole application or parts of it to reduce bandwidth as much as possible.
I have tried zipping it on my computer and I manage to reduce the size by 60% (I'm trying this on an example app which is 700Ko) ! 
I know there are some javascript libs to zip lines of code but what about a zipping procedure on the server hosting the app and unzipping it on the phone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Browsers and most servers (e.g. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)) support compression on transfer-level. You'll find tons of information when you [search Content-encoding compression](http://www.google.com/search?q=content-encoding+compress)

Comment: Good point, this one slipt out of my mine. So you think this is sufficient? ( maybe some crunching in all the js files, css and html would help too?)

Comment: That's a different story. There's a bunch of approaches you cold use (e.g. UglifyJS, data URLs, inlining JS and CSS to save requests, PNGcrush, JPEG mini, sprites generators, ...). You may want to have a look at [Steve Souder's blog](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/09/26/mobile-gmail-and-async-script-loading/) for more advanced techniques, or even develop your own compression toolchain, like I did (hundreds of lines of hacky Bash code ;)). Also keep in mind that some Frameworks like qooxdoo have many of those optimizations built-in.